A poor man given security by PM. Hindi movie
A poor man who met PM on an occasion is awarded with security. Security follows him wherever he goes. Initially the poor man likes all the attention but later it becomes a headache. It was s a color movie and made in Hindi language. Year must be between 2000-2016
He was given security due to some misunderstanding as he did not want it at first place. The poor man looked somewhat like Kay Kay Menon but was not him. I don't know about ending as I didn't watch complete movie and want to complete it. 

Zed Plus (2014) starring Adil Hussain as Aslam Puncturewala.
From one of the reviews:

Aslam is a poor fellow and lives by repairing bicycles and is also a
  Khadim(Priest) at a nearby Mosque. 
Prime minister is planning to visit his city and bizarre sequence of
  fortuitous events happen resulting in how this Khadim (Dargah
  attendant) shockingly ends up with Zed Plus security. What ensues is a
  fascinating game of political opportunism involving the Khadim and the
  top leaders of the two opposing political factions.

You can find details here.
